# Accessing the system log on Raspbian

Tags: pi-2, logfiles

How do I access the system logs in current versions of Raspbian?  Where are these logs stored?

Comment: Which log file?

Comment: The error log file.

Comment: That is an important detail that belongs in your question (and should have been included from the start), not the comments. Likewise the distro you are using as mentioned in @joan's answer. You may also want to look at the find command man find.

Comment: One thing which can be said with certainty about *the log file* is that it's somewhere on the SD card.

Comment: There isn't really a system wide log dedicated to just *errors*, so I have edited your question to reflect this.  Log messages are instead sorted in terms of *priority* and origin.  A low priority message may or may not be reporting an error.  Higher priority messages may be more likely to involve errors, but this is still not necessarily the case.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Raspbian comes with `systemd`. I prefer to use this progressive system. `Systemd` has a consistent journaling with `journalctl` with no need to know where log files are stored. But to answer your question if you also like to use `journald`, this is stored in `/var/log/journal`. For enabling persistent logging in `journald` and get access to it you have [1]:

> To enable persistent logging, create /var/log/journal:
>
> ```
>  mkdir -p /var/log/journal
>  systemd-tmpfiles --create --prefix /var/log/journal
> ```
>
> systemd will make the journal files owned by the "systemd-journal"
>   group and add an ACL for read permissions for users in the "adm"
>   group. To grant a user read access to the system journal, add them to
>   one of the two groups.
>
> This will allow you to look at previous boot logs with e. g.
>   "journalctl -b -1".
>
> If you enable persistent logging, consider uninstalling rsyslog or any
>   other system-log-daemon, to avoid logging everything twice.

Some examples how to get log "files": get last boot log

```
rpi3 ~$ journalctl -b
```

Get kernel logging (was `dmesg`)

```
rpi3 ~$ journalctl -k
```

Get continous showing log (as taken with `tail -f` on old style logs)

```
rpi3 ~$ journalctl -f
```

Get log from the end with many details

```
rpi3 ~$ journalctl -xe
```

Or get details from services, e.g. network

```
rpi3 ~$ systemctl status systemd-networkd
# or
rpi3 ~$ systemctl status networking
```

Try it. This already works with current logging. You do not need to have it persistent. But if you want a history you should make it persistent of course.

**preferences:**
[1] /usr/share/doc/systemd/README.Debian.gz

Answer (score 6):

I'm running Linux raspberrypi 4.14.98-v7+ and I can access system logs by running:

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

Answer (score 5):

Depends on the operating system you are using.

Raspbian puts most logs in directory `/var/log`.

Answer (score 1):

Which log file? There are many. Most of the log files are in /var/log.

However, there is a command called "dmesg" which allows you to read the kernel ring buffer (the kernel log). This will often tell you things that might have gone wrong with the boot sequence and is the most useful thing I've found to find out what is wrong.

I often use it as "dmesg | tail" or "dmesg | more"