# how to log and view system messages on PiZeroW?

Tags: raspberry-pi-os, raspberry-pi-os-buster, logfiles

My Pi stopped responding yesterday. It normally serves an html page with sensor data using apache. When I browsed to the IP I got 403. When I tried to SSH I got

> kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer

> Connection reset by 192.168.1.11 port 22

I cycled the power and it is back and appears to be functioning normally. The Python script collecting data from a sensor and logging it every 5 minutes using cron stopped about 36 hrs ago so it seems like a full system crash. Can anyone suggest where I should look for logs on RasPiOS Buster that might indicate what went wrong, or how I can get the Pi to create such logs, if they're not enabled by default?

Answer (score 1):

Login via ssh or console and look at /var/log/syslog using more, less, grep or your favourite editor.

Connection reset by peer is an error generated when the remote side drops the connection.   It implies that networking was up and that it established the connection but was dropped by USER software.

https://selivan.github.io/2017/02/07/rsyslog-log-forward-save-filename-handle-multi-line-failover.html

Comment: Thanks for the response. The card is 32GB and I've used 6GB so far so probably not an issue. I used journalctl as described in this post: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/79525/accessing-the-system-log-on-raspbian I didn't try this earlier because I misinterpreted the post as stating that a bunch of file creation was a needed before you could begin logging. I think that only applies to journald.

Comment: So if its not disk then its possible its memory..   The only issue is once a box runs out of disk or memory it possible that won't be any logs.. ;-)

Comment: So I suggest you monitor your system over hours, days etc and see if you have a memory leak..   e.g. Is your python script slowing devouring all of your memory?

Comment: you can even setup a script to top the contents of "top" into a log file on some interval (30 minutes maybe). This way you dont have to keep checking,  and you will get a better picture of how the memory usage changes over time. It may reveal you have a memory leak, but maybe not in the application you were expecting.

Comment: You could also setup rsyslog to forward the logs to different server.   That has some-chance of working even if your memory runs out..